# Custom MSCHART label

Tags: label, mschart

How can format the labels in mschart so that it contains X-Value and other value from database like this:

12 KG   ,  200 POUND ,    45 LIters

lets call it the MeasureUnit value and it is deffirent with each X-Value

help me please

I tried this but the label appears as 0 always

```
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBind(Data, XValue, YValue, "Label=" & YValue & ControlChars.Lf & LabelUnit)
```

Here is the Ans:

```
  Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBind(Data, XValue, YValue, "Unit=" & LabelUnit)
    Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = XValue
    Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = YValue

   For Each pnt As DataPoint In Chart1.Series(0).Points
        pnt.Label = "#VAL" & ControlChars.Lf & pnt.GetCustomProperty("Unit")

    Next
    Chart1.Series("Series1").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    Chart1.Series("Series1").ToolTip = "#VAL"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AxisLabel property

```
chart1.Series[i].Points[i].AxisLabel = yourValue; // here yourValue is the value returned by database
```

OR if your series already has data you can do

```
foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points)
{
     dp.AxisLabel = dp.XValue + "yourUnit" ; // or write your own logic here
}
```

Comment: HardCoding the value wont's help these are variables from database

Comment: You can assign the value from database. I hard coded as an example

Comment: I tried to pass a value from the database with the x,y values but when I assign it to Label Property as shown above ,the Label text appear 0 always

Comment: Do it after databinding as i have explained above. Its AxisLabel property

Comment: Once again the unit should be loaded with xValue and YValue From database not hardcoding it or For eaching the points again

Comment: Thanks,I did it ,Although I wasn't convince with your idea ,but later on I found there is no other way.